# Google analytics event tracking on Multiple accounts not working

Tags: google-analytics

I have multiple accounts on some pages - I am trying to track some events - they fire beautifully when I test them on Fiddler - but they are not coming into my analytics - the code is below - what am I doing wrong?  Three days later any help would be GREAT.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

    _gaq.push(
        //tracking for first
        ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1'],
        ['_trackPageview'],

        //tracking for second
        ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-16'],
        ['b._trackPageview'],
        ['b._trackEvent'],
        ['b._trackPageLoadTime']
    );

    (function() { 
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true; 
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www')
        + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ||
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga); 
    })();
</script>

<li><a href="#anchor_2" class="gray"
onClick="_gaq.push(['b._trackEvent', 'button3', 'menu', 'clicked']);">link</a></li>
```

Comment: Here you can find a detailed example http://marketlytics.com/adding-multiple-google-analytics-tracking-codes-to-webpage/

Answer (score 1):

Note that `_trackPageLoadTime` is deprecated now. You don't need that anymore. Also the event on the top doesn't make sense. Events must have at least two string parameters and they have optional 3rd string parameter and 4th integer parameter.

So your code on the top should look like this:

```
 var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
_gaq.push(
  //tracking for first
  ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1'],
  ['_trackPageview'],
  //tracking for second
  ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-16'],
  ['b._trackPageview']
```

Then when you're firing the event you are only sending this to your `b` account and I believe you want to send to both. So for that reason you should do something like this:

```
<li><a href="#anchor_2" class="gray" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'button3', 'menu', 'clicked']);_gaq.push(['b._trackEvent', 'button3', 'menu', 'clicked']);">take me somewhere</a></li>
```