# pushing events to multiple profiles

Tags: google-analytics

We are testing a link tracking solution and at the moment would like to have the events show up on two different accounts. We have the setup like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(
  ['_setAccount', 'UA-516606-1'],
  ['_trackPageview'],
  ['_setDomainName', 'du.edu'],
  ['b._setAccount', 'UA-516606-24'],
  ['b._trackPageview'],
  ['b._setDomainName', 'du.edu']
);
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

We were using the tracking code found at http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527, but I don't have the knowhow to modify that to work for multiple accounts. The solution here: [Google analytics event tracking on Multiple accounts not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264348/google-analytics-event-tracking-on-multiple-accounts-not-working) doesn't quite work because of this. Is it possible to add a b account to a recordOutboundLink function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a different `recordOutboundLink` function.

```js
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
  _gaq.push(
    ['_trackEvent', category, action],
    ['b._trackEvent', category, action]
  );
  setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100);
}
```

And then on your link

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com');return false;">
```